# Is there a free tool to profile the execution time of Java methods?

Tags: java, methods, benchmarking

I need to know the usage by other applications, in time of execution, of java methods of an api created in my project, does someone know any free tool to know this?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you define more clearly what you want to do? "Monitorize" is not a word, as far as I know.

Comment: Sorry for my bad English, I wanted to say monitor or profile.

Answer (score 2):

Seems as if you need a profiler. [VisualVM](https://visualvm.dev.java.net/) contains one. It may not be the most powerful, but it's rather easy to use and it ships with the Sun JDK since 1.6.0_07.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can download [Netbeans profiler](http://profiler.netbeans.org/), in it you can view statistics and threads execution.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you could try to apply some aspect oriented programming. Logging seems to be the classic example of its usage. Try e.g. [AspectJ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AspectJ).

Answer (score 0):

Check [JaMon](http://jamonapi.sourceforge.net/). Works with olds JDKS, and is very easy to use.